# Not able to set list2 in Adobe Launch in custom code

Tags: analytics, adobe-launch

I am trying to set list2 in my analytics call through custom code but it is not getting set.

This issue comes with `s.tl()` only while with `s.t()` method, it is triggered correctly.

Below is the code :-

```
s.addEvent("event12", true);
s.linkTrackVars = "list2";
s.list2 = "Data"
s.tl(this, "d", "Download", s);
```

If I place logger just before beacon call, it shows the value. However, when I click the button and check for same, only "event12" get fired and not "list2".

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check to see if you have a `doPlugins` callback function defined, and if so, check if `list2` or `linkTrackVars` is getting overwritten somewhere within it.

Comment: I checked the above things but it is still giving error

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code on lululemon:

[image]

Conclusion:

You're overwriting either the listvar or the linkTrackVars somewhere else. As @Crayton Mentioned above, doPlugins would be a good spot for it.

But it actually can be overwritten anywhere. In any rule that fires prior, or the s code, or any DE affected.

1. Paste your code into the console. Execute. Do you see the listvar populated? If yes, then your problem is in rules, so check them. You're not supposed to reassign linktrackvars. Always use the s.apl() plugin.
2. If no, however, then your problem is definitely in doPlugins. Sometimes I have it when I have silent catches in s code. Pageviews would have all vars populated, but links would have mixed results. Check your error reporting in the catches in doPlugins. I suggest having all code in doPlugins in a try catch.